# fetch() from url, cant access object, console.log() works

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have the 3 following lines of code:

```
const response = await fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v3/alpha/${countrycode}`);
let json = await response.json();
console.log("this is my json file: ", json.borders)
```

The problem is, when I do this I receive in my console log `undefined` but I want to access the 'borders' property of the object.
On the other side, if I change the third line into this:

```
console.log("this is my json file: ", json)
```

I get the full object which looks like this:

> {"altSpellings": ["DE", "Federal Republic of Germany", "Bundesrepublik
> Deutschland"], "area": 357114, "borders": ["AUT", "BEL", "CZE", "DNK",
> "FRA", "LUX", "NLD", "POL", "CHE"], "capital": ["Berlin"], "cca2":
> "DE", "cca3": "DEU", "ccn3": "276", "cioc": "GER", "currencies":
> {"EUR": [Object]}, "demonyms": {"eng": [Object], "fra": [Object]},
> "flag": "", "flags": ["https://restcountries.com/data/deu.svg",
> "https://restcountries.com/data/png/deu.png"], "idd": {"root": "+4",
> "suffixes": [Array]}, "independent": true, "landlocked": false,
> "languages": {"deu": "German"}, "latlng": [51, 9], "name": {"common":
> "Germany", "nativeName": [Object], "official": "Federal Republic of
> Germany"}, "region": "Europe", "status": "officially-assigned",
> "subregion": "Western Europe", "tld": [".de"], "translations": {"ces":
> [Object], "deu": [Object], "est": [Object], "fin": [Object], "fra":
> [Object], "hrv": [Object], "hun": [Object], "ita": [Object], "jpn":
> [Object], "kor": [Object], "nld": [Object], "per": [Object], "pol":
> [Object], "por": [Object], "rus": [Object], "slk": [Object], "spa":
> [Object], "swe": [Object], "urd": [Object], "zho": [Object]},
> "unMember": true}

What can I do to be able to access all those values, or just like in my example the 'borders' , what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response is an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), not an [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). Change the 3rd line to this to access the property.

```js
    console.log("this is my json file: ", json[0].borders)
```